# Execute bash commands in a curses window

Tags: c, bash, ncurses, curses

This question is certain to exist, but I cannot find it anywhere...

I have a (n)curses window which I would like to dedicate to a bash shell (window 2) while concurrently displaying items in Window 1:

```
+-------------------------------+
|                 |             |
|                 |             |
|    WINDOW 1     |  WINDOW 2   |
|                 |             |
|                 |             |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

How would I perform this? I need it to accept input and display output as if I had just opened another terminal - and if possible - host is *own* curses sessions (such as if the dialog command is called)

I am using c.

Comment: That's a complex problem to solve. Not sure a question on Stack Overflow is going to help you.

Comment: @NikosC.I'm not looking for someone to hand me the answer, I'm I only want a direction to go in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux and screen can subdivide the terminal window into panes, which would let you do what you're asking about.  Both use low-level features (terminfo or termcap) of ncurses.  Doing it yourself at a high level would not be a short project, since you would have to manage the pseudo terminal connection to make bash run, etc.

bash expects to run in a *terminal* (a "tty", if you prefer), and if you wrap an application around it, making it run in a *window*, you have to provide connections for its input/output/error, making those act like a terminal.  That is what a pseudo-terminal is: a collection of system calls which let a program setup, configure, operate and close connections to a process (such as bash) which need to act like a terminal.

Programs that use pseudo-terminals include (no surprise) terminal emulators, special applications such as [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [luit](https://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html) (e.g., the [sys.c file](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/luit-snapshots/blob/master/sys.c)).

Here are a few links to further reading:

- [Using pseudo-terminals (pty) to control interactive programs](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html)
- [grantpt - grant access to the slave pseudo-terminal device](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/grantpt.html) (POSIX)
- [ptsname - get name of the slave pseudo-terminal device](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ptsname.html#)
- [posix_openpt - open a pseudo-terminal device](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_openpt.html#)
- [unlockpt - unlock a pseudo-terminal master/slave pair](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlockpt.html#)

Comment: Could you provide any resources on or shortly explain pseudo terminal connection?